# Load Micronaut and Spring Plugin with Gradle in multi-module project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, micronaut, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build a multi-module project with Gradle with a root build.gradle file. One module is a Spring Boot website and the other a Micronaut authorization server.

My issue arises when I'm trying to load the Micronaut plugin (v. 3.7.9) and the Spring Boot plugin (v. 3.0.5). Gradle throws following exception:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'io.micronaut.application', version: '3.7.9']
> Failed to apply plugin class 'io.micronaut.gradle.MicronautMinimalApplicationPlugin'.
   > Cannot add a configuration with name 'developmentOnly' as a configuration with that name already exists.
```

I can get rid of the issue when adding `apply false` to either the Micronaut or Spring plugin when declaring all plugins at the top of the `build.gradle` file. But I don't think this is how you're supposed to do this.

Adding either

```
configurations {
        developmentOnly
    }

//or

configurations {
        developmentOnly {
            extendsFrom implementation
        }
    }
```

didn't fix the issue.

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
//file:noinspection DependencyNotationArgument
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id "com.github.node-gradle.node" version "3.0.1"
    id 'jacoco'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "7.1.2"
    id "io.micronaut.application" version "3.7.9"
}

allprojects {
    group = 'com.ffhs'
    version = '1.0'
    sourceCompatibility = '17'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/dependencies.gradle"
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'application'
}

project("RecipePlatform") {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

    dependencies {
        implementation libs.dataMongo
        implementation libs.starterWeb
        implementation libs.graphql
        implementation libs.starterActuator

        testImplementation libsTest.starterTest
        testImplementation libsTest.jupiterApi
        testImplementation libsTest.jupiterParams
        testImplementation libsTest.mockitoCore
        testImplementation libsTest.junit4

        testRuntimeOnly libsRuntimeTest.jupiterEngine
    }

    application {
        mainClass = "com.ffhs.identityprovider.Application"
    }

    tasks.named('test') {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
        dependsOn test // tests are required to run before generating the report
    }

    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "0.8.8"
        reportsDirectory = layout.buildDirectory.dir('customJacocoReportDir')
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.required = false
            csv.required = false
            html.outputLocation = layout.buildDirectory.dir('jacocoHtml')
        }
    }
}

project("frontend"){
    apply plugin: 'com.github.node-gradle.node'

    node {
        download = true
        version = '18.16.0'
    }

    tasks.register('buildReactApp', NodeTask) {
        dependsOn 'npmInstall'
        script = project.file('node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js')
        args = [
                '--mode', 'development',
                '--entry', './src/main/webapp/javascript/Main.jsx',
                '-o', './src/main/resources/static/dist'
        ]
    }

    processResources.dependsOn 'buildReactApp'
    clean.delete << file('node_modules')
    clean.delete << file('src/main/resources/static/dist')
}

project("IdentityProvider") {
    apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
    apply plugin: 'io.micronaut.application'

    dependencies {
        annotationProcessor libsAnnotationProcessor.httpValidator

        implementation libs.httpClient
        implementation libs.jackson
        implementation libs.jakartaAnnotation

        runtimeOnly libsRuntime.logback
    }

    configurations {
        developmentOnly {
            extendsFrom implementation
        }
    }

    application {
        mainClass = "com.ffhs.identityprovider.Application"
    }

    graalvmNative.toolchainDetection = false
    micronaut {
        runtime("netty")
        testRuntime("junit5")
        processing {
            incremental(true)
            annotations("com.ffhs.*")
        }
    }
}
```